# collectstatic not a valid subcommand for django-admin.py using django 1.4 on EC2

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, django-admin, django-staticfiles

I have an Amazon Linux instance running on EC2. I'm trying to get up and running with the staticfiles app for Django. However, when I try to run:

> django-admin.py collectstatic

It returns "unknown command: 'collectstatic'". And, indeed, when I type `django-admin.py help`, it lists out the available sub-commands, and `collectstatic` isn't among them.

I'm running Django 1.4, and have checked my project's settings.py, where INSTALLED_APPS does include `django.contrib.staticfiles`.

Any idea what could be causing this? Is there something specific I need to do to set up / configure staticfiles so that the collectstatic subcommand is available within django-admin.py?

Answer (score 1):

try running `./manage.py help` in your project root directory - `collectstatic` should be a subcommand there.

Comment: Thanks. Apologies for the newbie mistake.

Comment: This is strange that you have to use `manage.py` instead of `django-admin.py`. The latest docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic) clearly states `django-admin.py collectstatic`.

Comment: see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-py-and-manage-py)

Answer (score 0):

List of commands is limited based on your permissions. Try running sudo manage.py collectstatic.

Comment: Could you please expand on this? What kind of permissions is Django looking for?

Comment: @bvukelic UNIX / Linux permissions assigned to the system user you are running the commands as. If you don't have access to the folders / files that the command needs, you won't see it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I figured it out meanwhile, and it was a missing directory in my case.